# Nginx конфигурация location для директорий

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, веб-сервер

У меня есть веб-проект с такой структурой:

```
/home/box/web
          |---public
          |   |---img
          |   |---css
          |   |---js
          |   |index.html
          |   |1.jpeg
          |---uploads
          |   |1.jpeg
          |---etc
          |   |nginx.conf
```

Проект запущен под nginx, который сконфигурирован так:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    include       ./sites-enabled/test.conf;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;
}
```

`./sites-enabled/test.conf` это симлинк для моего `/home/box/web/etc/nginx.conf`, который выглядит так:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.log;
    root       /home/box/web/;

    location / {
        root /home/box/web/public/;
        index index.htm index.html;
    }

    location /uploads/ {
        root /home/box/web/uploads/;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что у меня не обрабатывается локейшен /uploads/. Обращение по адресу `localhost` возвращает индексную страницу, `http://localhost/1.jpeg` возвращает картинку, но обращение по адресу `http://localhost/uploads/1.jpeg` возвращает ошибку 404: файл не найден. Хотя картинка в этой директории есть.

Что у меня не так с локейшенами? Почему /uploads/ никогда не обрабатывается?

Как мне настроить, чтобы файлы, удовлетворяющие некоторым условиям, отдавались из разных директорий? Например, чтобы картинки с расширениями отдавались из /home/box/web/public.

Comment: Замените `root` на `alias`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо. Вроде, заработало. А почему alias?